# Rails 3 - URL Helpers With Scoped Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, urlhelper

I have a scoped resource in my routes file:

```
scope :module => "physical" do
    resources :mymodels
end
```

Using '> rake routes' I get the standard routes, including:

```
mymodel GET    /mymodels/:id(.:format)    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"physical/mymodels"}
```

However when I use the console (and this is what's failing in my tests) to get the url for instances of Mymodel I get errors:

```
> m = Physical::Mymodel.new
> => {...model_attributes...}
> m.save
> => true
> app.url_for(m)
> NoMethodError: undefined method `physical_mymodel_url' for #<ActionDispatch::Integration::Session:0x00000105b15228>
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:175:in `method_missing'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:114:in `polymorphic_url'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:133:in `url_for'
from (irb):13
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

This might be a gotcha, but Mymodel is also a subclass using the standard Rails single table inheritance.

Any thoughts?  Why is it looking for physical_mymodel_url instead of mymodel_url? Any ideas for workarounds so that I can still use the unprefixed routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only using the scope to tell it the module where the controller can be found in. If you want to use the `physical` prefix on your routes then you could do this:

```
scope :module => "physical", :as => "physical" do
  resources :mymodel
end
```

Alternatively, you could just use the `namespace` method which will do the same thing:

```
namespace :physical do
  resources :mymodel
end
```

Comment: I want to *ommit* the prefix on the route helper method.  It seems to be expecting physical_mymodel_url based on the error message, when I want it to use mymodel_url.  mymodel_url should work based on the rake routes output.

Comment: It turns out that the url_for method calls the ActiveRecord::Naming plural method on the ActiveRecord class.  This returns "physical_mymodels" which is the basis for the rest of the URL logic.  There's no tie-in to the routes file at all so there's no way to know that the model isn't using the prefix.  Looks like I either need to use the prefixed paths using Ryan Bigg's solution or modify the ActiveRecord base for all of the models in the Physical module to override the url_for and strip off the module prefix.